# Adding the check boxes in the TREEVIEW in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

i want to add the **check box** to the child node of a certain parent node in the tree view in my application...How should i add it?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt :-yes in the windows form and in "c sharp"

Comment: @Mitch Wheat :- no unfortunately it is not woking :(

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375799/winforms-treeview-with-both-radios-and-checkboxes) is a simular question, hope this helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms TreeView with both radios and checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375799/winforms-treeview-with-both-radios-and-checkboxes)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`TreeView` has a property with the name `CheckBoxes`, if set to `true`, it shows checkboxes for all child nodes.

Comment: Can't find this property in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 12):

The TreeView API only allows you to add/remove checkboxes for EVERY node. If that's what you want, then the answer is easy - use the TreeView's CheckBoxes property.

If you want a checkbox for a particular node in the tree only, then it gets tricky. .NET doesn't directly support that. You can get the tree to accept it using Win32 message overrides, see the link below for a solution elsewhere:

http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/05/winforms-treeview-hide-checkbox-of-treenode/

Answer (score 6):

You can't show checkboxes only for some `TreeNode`s - only for all of them or none at all.
To enable the checkboxes for your tree set the [`CheckBoxes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes.aspx) property to `true`.