# Windows Forms/TreeView: How do I put CheckBoxes only on the leaves?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Selecting CheckBoxes=true on the treeview puts checkboxes on every node. I only want them on the leaves? How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes

Comment: This has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093467/adding-the-check-boxes-in-the-treeview-in-c-sharp Look for reference to http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/05/winforms-treeview-hide-checkbox-of-treenode/

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement an ownerdraw event handler for the nodes like this:

```
treeView.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
treeView.DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.treeView_DrawNode);

private void treeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if(NodeWithCheckBox(e.Node))
    {
       // draw entry with checkbox
       e.DrawDefault = false;
    }
    else
    {
       e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```