# How can I draw a circle checkboxes in the third level of a treeview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a 3-level treeview in my win form. All three levels are checkboxes, but in the last one I have checkboxes that should act like radio buttons. So, I want that the square becomes a circle, so as not to confuse the user.

I've tried to implement the `MyTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)` method but in the last level of the treeview the square remains square.

*The best solution would be to directly implement the radio button, but that is not suitable in my context.*

How can I do this? (see: https://ibb.co/StY8HvG)

I want to implement a method that only redraws the checkbox, I don't want to change the behavior of my checkboxes on the last level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms TreeView with both radios and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375799/winforms-treeview-with-both-radios-and-checkboxes)

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I have tried that yet.

Comment: If you posted your DrawNode code, we could probably solve this for you.

Comment: That is the last version of my code: `if (e.Node.Parent == null)
            {
                e.Node.NodeFont = new Font(treeViewEx.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Node.Bounds, Color.Blue, Color.White);
                e.DrawDefault = false;
            }
            else
                e.DrawDefault = true;` in "else" I want to draw a checkable circle, but if I use the `FillEllipse` method, I obtain a black circle and it is not a "circle checkbox" (radio button). 

@LarsTech

Comment: You would have to use the RadioButtonRenderer class.  You probably have to change the DrawMode to OwnerDrawAll.  This means you can't do `e.DrawDefault = true;` and have to draw the entire node.